# compiling c++ 11 program the simple way using makefile

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, makefile

Got an assignment to write a simple program in c++11 which contains the following files:

- main.cpp
- house.h
- tree.h

The main function is obviously in the main.cpp file.
main.cpp includes the 2 header files and uses them.

when I tried to compile on Linux, I wrote:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -o prog
```

And I got a **prog** file which I could run.

Then I tried to compile it using a makefile, what I did was this:

```
all:
    g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -o prog
```

and hit **make all**

Sadly it doesn't work.
Tried to search the web for how to do it properly, no luck.
Can you tell me how it needs to be done?

**Also**, how to make a smart compile? i.e. compile only when the above files are changed.

Thanks!

Comment: "sadly it doesn't work" what it mean? Don't compile? Is there some error mesages? Second string must start with tabulation

Comment: Make sure the `g++` is indented with a `TAB` not spaces.

Comment: "how to make a smart compile?" - read the make documentation This Q&A is not geared up to providing tutorials and `make` needs some time and effort to learn. But if you're going to  be a programmer its pretty essential imho.

Answer (score 0):

In `Makefile`

```
all:
<TAB>g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -o prog
```

This will work, Please pay attention here that `<TAB>` is the tab character that we need to insert.

Simply compiled it by issuing

```
make
```

Or for a simple cases, `make` provides a short cut with default rule. You can compile our code `without using Makefile`.

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c+=11 -Wall -pedantic -pthread make main
```

But this approach will name the program name as name of the file, i.e. main here, instead of `prog` as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Makefile` with just the following lines and check this out:

```
CFLAGS += -g -O2 -Wall -W -pedantic
CXXFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) -std=c++11
CFLAGS += -pthread
LDFLAGS += -pthread
```

And type `make main`. Make will search its built-in rules and discover that there is a way to get from `main.cpp` to a compiled program named `main`. It will then execute a built-in rule that looks something like:

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

If you want to just type `make` then you can add:

```
all: main
```

And the built-in implicit rules will build `main` for you when you type `make`.